# Up arrow not showing Octave history commands from an executable script

Tags: input, octave, readline

If I run `$octave -q --no-gui`, pressing up arrow will show past commands. Now, when executing this script

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -q

a = input(">> ", "s");
```

it will prompt for an input, but when pressing up arrow it shows the characters `^[[A`. This is for version 4.0.0, but in older versions, like 3.2.4, up arrow was operating fine in the executable script, showing the commands in the history file, just as the other prompt. I've checked and both runs are looking to the same history file, so may be the thing is in the way input is taken.

Really need this feature for a programming environment, any help is welcome.

Update: these options for Octave initialization might be related:

```
--line-editing          Force readline use for command-line editing.
--no-line-editing       Don't use readline for command-line editing.
```

because `$octave -q --no-gui --no-line-editing` produces the same result of the script (i.e. no history, just `^[[A`). So, now the question is how to launch Octave from the script with the `--line-editing` option, as if added, it will failed:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.0.0/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui: invalid option -- ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

If the script does launch without the `-q` option, then it allows long options, so just create the script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave --line-editing
```

and it works fine, now the history shows up.